# Creating and installing rpm package

Tags: rpm, centos5

I am using CentOS 5.
I have created an rpm spec file for a module. It has compile time dependency on a shared library, libavro to be precise. 
To that end, I downloaded, built and installed libavro-1.5.1.so.21. It got installed at /usr/local/lib by default. I also edited ld.so.conf to include /usr/local/lib.
I executed ldconfig to regenerate ld cache.
After the above steps, I generated the rpm for my module.
When I try to install the rpm on the same machine I built it, I get failed dependency error:- 
libavro-1.5.4.so.22()(64bit) is needed by mymodule-1.1-1.x86

I don't understand why should it fail on a shared lib it linked to while building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing libavro-1.5.4 instead. rpm is looking for the logical name (soname) of the required libraries so that's why the installation fails.

Answer (score 1):

Having the shared library alone is not enough: you need the headers as well, and the `.so` link to be able to link against it.

Try and find a `-devel` package along with the library package and install it. Add the devel package as a `BuildRequires` in your spec file.

Oh, and DO NOT build your RPMs as root -- you don't do that, do you?